# How can i connect to the oracle database between docker containers?

Tags: java, oracle, docker, docker-compose

I have two containers that is created from **docker-compose**, one has **api** with **springboot** and the other **oracle** database, however it does'n connect the **api** to the database and I already ran out options, I tried configure the connection in the `aplication.properties` and also `docker-compose.yml`

This is `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  app:
    image: "bm_spring_boot:latest"
    build:
      context: ./BmApiRestV2/
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: api_spring
    depends_on:
      - db
    ports:
      - 8888:8080
    environment:
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:oracle:thin:@//db:49161/xe
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME=system
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD=oracle
    networks:
      spring-net:
        aliases:
          - spring-host

  db:
    image: oracleinanutshell/oracle-xe-11g:latest
    container_name: oracle_db
    ports:
      - 49161:1521
      - 5500:5500
    environment:
      - ORACLE_ALLOW_REMOTE=true
    networks:
      spring-net:
        aliases:
          - db-host
networks:
  spring-net:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      driver: default
```

`Dockerfile`

```
ARG VERSION=8-jdk-slim
FROM openjdk:${VERSION}
ARG JAR_FILE=BmApiRestV2
COPY "./target/${JAR_FILE}.jar" "app.jar"
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT [ "java","-jar","app.jar"]
```

`aplication.properties`

```
#spring.datasource.username=system
#spring.datasource.password=oracle
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
#DOCKER
#spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@ (DESCRIPTION =    (ADDRESS_LIST =      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = db)(PORT = 49161))    )    (CONNECT_DATA =      (SID = xe)    )  )
```

(The connection was commented because in the `docker-compose` it's configured)

I appreciate the help (My apologies for my english)

-------------- UPDATE --------------

**Connection test**

```
 ping db
PING db (172.20.0.2) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from oracle_db.imagenspring_spring-net (172.20.0.2): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.221 ms
64 bytes from oracle_db.imagenspring_spring-net (172.20.0.2): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.072 ms
64 bytes from oracle_db.imagenspring_spring-net (172.20.0.2): icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.072 ms
64 bytes from oracle_db.imagenspring_spring-net (172.20.0.2): icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.072 ms
64 bytes from oracle_db.imagenspring_spring-net (172.20.0.2): icmp_seq=5 ttl=64 time=0.144 ms
64 bytes from oracle_db.imagenspring_spring-net (172.20.0.2): icmp_seq=6 ttl=64 time=0.071 ms
64 bytes from oracle_db.imagenspring_spring-net (172.20.0.2): icmp_seq=7 ttl=64 time=0.161 ms
64 bytes from oracle_db.imagenspring_spring-net (172.20.0.2): icmp_seq=8 ttl=64 time=0.063 ms
^C
--- db ping statistics ---
8 packets transmitted, 8 received, 0% packet loss, time 7090ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.063/0.109/0.221/0.054 ms
root@2254b03a8ef4:/#
```

Comment: Take a look at the app container's log. `docker logs -f app_1`

Comment: Look at this @RenéLink
`GenericDAO.findByCriteria. Causa: Failed to obtain JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection (CONNECTION_ID=ovjLg/qBR/CvVN1B4sRQEw==).`

Comment: If you place containers in the same network, you need to connect to the original port 1521 and hostname as you set in alias: db-host

Comment: If you want to connect to the bridge interface you need to use ip address of the host interface to port 49161

Comment: Ok, i got it. but i tried with the ip address and not work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### TLDR

Change the port to 1521 in your connection string.

### Extended version

Your services and networking are configure properly. Both containers are in the same docker network, which allows them to communicate with each other.

Also, contrary to some of the comments, all 3 ways of calling the containers are correct:

- db
- db-host
- oracle_db.

This can be easily verified using a simplified `docker-compose.yml`, just to test the connectivity:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  app:
    image: busybox
    command: "sh -c 'sleep 3600;'"
    networks:
      spring-net:
        aliases:
          - app-host
  db:
    image: busybox
    command: "sh -c 'sleep 3600;'"
    container_name: oracle_db
    networks:
      spring-net:
        aliases:
          - db-host
networks:
  spring-net:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      driver: default
```

If you try to resolve the names - they all point to the same container:

```
/ # ping db
PING db (172.21.0.2): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 172.21.0.2: seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.593 ms
^C
--- db ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max = 0.593/0.593/0.593 ms
/ # ping oracle_db
PING oracle_db (172.21.0.2): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 172.21.0.2: seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.213 ms
^C
--- oracle_db ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max = 0.213/0.213/0.213 ms
/ # ping db-host
PING db-host (172.21.0.2): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 172.21.0.2: seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.334 ms
^C
--- db-host ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max = 0.334/0.334/0.334 ms
```

In fact, the problem seems to be with your connection string:

```
- SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:oracle:thin:@//db:49161/xe
```

port `49161` is the host port, while your connecting to the container (`db`). In this case you should be using the `1521` port, which the server inside the container is bound to.

Comment: Ok ... but that port is being used in local, anyway i tested the connection and it's all right

Comment: What do you mean it's all right? It works when you switched to port 1521?

Comment: I updated the question, you can see that. I can´t switch to port 1521, cause is being used.

Comment: Your port 1521 might be in use on your docker host. It is still available in your container. In your conn string you’re refererring to your container (db), which has port 1521 open. If you were refererring to the docker host you could use the other port.

Comment: Port 1521 on my host is probably used by oracle

Comment: i changed the port, now i have this log response `Failed to obtain JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1`

Comment: That looks more like an errror you might want to check in the db server’s log files, not a connectivity issue anymore

Comment: I aprecciate the help men, you save my life