# Unable to connect Oracle 19 database into Django container with Oracle database running into another container

Tags: python, django, oracle, docker, docker-compose

I am pretty new on Docker and I am trying to run a Django application with Oracle 19 database with Docker thanks to a `docker-compose.dev.yml` file. The problem is that my database container works but not my Django application which fails to connect to database. Here's the file :

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  oracle-database:
    image: icsvaccart/oracle19c:latest
    volumes:
      - ./data/db:/opt/oracle/oradata
    ports:
      - "1521:1521"
      - "5500:5500"

  django-back-end:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    env_file:
      - pythonPOC/.env
    depends_on:
      - oracle-database
```

Then I ran the command `docker compose -f docker-compose.dev.yml up --build` and after a couple of minutes, the process ends with the following complete logs :

> ```
> (venv) PS D:\Vianney\Documents\Projets\pythonPOC> docker compose -d -f docker-compose.dev.yml up --build
> Building 439.7s (11/11) FINISHED
> [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                                                            0.0s 
> transferring dockerfile: 32B                                                                                                                                                                                             0.0s 
> [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                                                               0.0s 
> transferring context: 34B                                                                                                                                                                                                0.0s 
> [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/python:3                                                                                                                                                                     1.5s 
> [auth] library/python:pull token for registry-1.docker.io                                                                                                                                                                   0.0s 
> [1/5] FROM docker.io/library/python:3@sha256:fc809ada71c087cec7e2d2244bcb9fba137638978a669f2aaf6267db43e89fdf                                                                                                               0.0s 
> [internal] load build context                                                                                                                                                                                               0.1s 
> transferring context: 16.98kB                                                                                                                                                                                            0.1s 
> CACHED [2/5] WORKDIR /app                                                                                                                                                                                                   0.0s 
> CACHED [3/5] COPY requirements.txt /app                                                                                                                                                                                     0.0s 
> CACHED [4/5] RUN pip install -r requirements.txt                                                                                                                                                                            0.0s 
> [5/5] COPY . .                                                                                                                                                                                                            417.3s 
> exporting to image                                                                                                                                                                                                         17.7s 
> exporting layers                                                                                                                                                                                                        17.7s 
> writing image sha256:f7909ee3f0cf378b86a4c6d64bc7c37ad69b1014cfea06b345cb9345e6310365                                                                                                                                    0.0s 
> naming to docker.io/library/pythonpoc-django-back-end                                                                                                                                                                    0.0s 
>
> Use 'docker scan' to run Snyk tests against images to find vulnerabilities and learn how to fix them
> time="2022-10-28T16:04:32+02:00" level=warning msg="Found orphan containers ([pythonpoc-web-1 pythonpoc-db-1]) for this project. If you removed or renamed this service in your compose file, you can run this command with the --rem
> ove-orphans flag to clean it up."
> Running 2/2
> Container pythonpoc-oracle-database-1  Recreated                                                                                                                                                                             0.2s 
> Container pythonpoc-django-back-end-1  Recreated                                                                                                                                                                             0.8s
> Attaching to pythonpoc-django-back-end-1, pythonpoc-oracle-database-1
> pythonpoc-oracle-database-1  | ORACLE EDITION: ENTERPRISE
> pythonpoc-oracle-database-1  | 
> pythonpoc-oracle-database-1  | LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on 28-OCT-2022 14:04:33
> pythonpoc-oracle-database-1  | 
> pythonpoc-oracle-database-1  | Copyright (c) 1991, 2019, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
> pythonpoc-oracle-database-1  | 
> pythonpoc-oracle-database-1  | Starting /opt/oracle/product/19c/dbhome_1/bin/tnslsnr: please wait...
> pythonpoc-oracle-database-1  | 
> pythonpoc-oracle-database-1  | TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
> pythonpoc-oracle-database-1  | System parameter file is /opt/oracle/product/19c/dbhome_1/network/admin/listener.ora
> pythonpoc-oracle-database-1  | Log messages written to /opt/oracle/diag/tnslsnr/ac86e0fda652/listener/alert/log.xml
> pythonpoc-oracle-database-1  | Listening on: (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(KEY=EXTPROC1)))
> pythonpoc-oracle-database-1  | Listening on: (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=0.0.0.0)(PORT=1521)))
> pythonpoc-oracle-database-1  | 
> pythonpoc-oracle-database-1  | Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC1)))
> pythonpoc-oracle-database-1  | STATUS of the LISTENER
> pythonpoc-oracle-database-1  | ------------------------
> pythonpoc-oracle-database-1  | Alias                     LISTENER
> pythonpoc-oracle-database-1  | Version                   TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
> pythonpoc-oracle-database-1  | Start Date                28-OCT-2022 14:04:33
> pythonpoc-oracle-database-1  | Uptime                    0 days 0 hr. 0 min. 0 sec
> pythonpoc-oracle-database-1  | Trace Level               off
> pythonpoc-oracle-database-1  | Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
> pythonpoc-oracle-database-1  | SNMP                      OFF
> pythonpoc-oracle-database-1  | Listener Parameter File   /opt/oracle/product/19c/dbhome_1/network/admin/listener.ora
> pythonpoc-oracle-database-1  | Listener Log File         /opt/oracle/diag/tnslsnr/ac86e0fda652/listener/alert/log.xml
> pythonpoc-oracle-database-1  | Listening Endpoints Summary...
> pythonpoc-oracle-database-1  |   (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(KEY=EXTPROC1)))
> pythonpoc-oracle-database-1  |   (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=0.0.0.0)(PORT=1521)))
> pythonpoc-oracle-database-1  | The listener supports no services
> pythonpoc-oracle-database-1  | The command completed successfully
> pythonpoc-oracle-database-1  | 
> pythonpoc-oracle-database-1  | SQL*Plus: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on Fri Oct 28 14:04:33 2022
> pythonpoc-oracle-database-1  | Version 19.3.0.0.0
> pythonpoc-oracle-database-1  | 
> pythonpoc-oracle-database-1  | Copyright (c) 1982, 2019, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
> pythonpoc-oracle-database-1  | 
> pythonpoc-oracle-database-1  | Connected to an idle instance.
> pythonpoc-oracle-database-1  | 
> pythonpoc-django-back-end-1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
> pythonpoc-django-back-end-1  |   File "src/oracledb/impl/thin/connection.pyx", line 99, in oracledb.thin_impl.ThinConnImpl._connect_with_address
> pythonpoc-django-back-end-1  |   File "src/oracledb/impl/thin/protocol.pyx", line 145, in oracledb.thin_impl.Protocol._connect_phase_one
> pythonpoc-django-back-end-1  |   File "src/oracledb/impl/thin/protocol.pyx", line 256, in oracledb.thin_impl.Protocol._connect_tcp
> pythonpoc-django-back-end-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/socket.py", line 850, in create_connection
> pythonpoc-django-back-end-1  |     raise exceptions[0]
> pythonpoc-django-back-end-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/socket.py", line 835, in create_connection
> pythonpoc-django-back-end-1  |     sock.connect(sa)
> pythonpoc-django-back-end-1  | OSError: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address
> pythonpoc-django-back-end-1  | 
> pythonpoc-django-back-end-1  | The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
> pythonpoc-django-back-end-1  | 
> pythonpoc-django-back-end-1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
> pythonpoc-django-back-end-1  |   File "/app/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
> pythonpoc-django-back-end-1  |     main()
> pythonpoc-django-back-end-1  |   File "/app/manage.py", line 18, in main
> pythonpoc-django-back-end-1  |     execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
> pythonpoc-django-back-end-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 446, in execute_from_command_line
> pythonpoc-django-back-end-1  |     utility.execute()
> pythonpoc-django-back-end-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 386, in execute
> pythonpoc-django-back-end-1  |     settings.INSTALLED_APPS
> pythonpoc-django-back-end-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 92, in __getattr__
> pythonpoc-django-back-end-1  |     self._setup(name)
> pythonpoc-django-back-end-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 79, in _setup
> pythonpoc-django-back-end-1  |     self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
> pythonpoc-django-back-end-1  |                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> pythonpoc-django-back-end-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 190, in __init__
> pythonpoc-django-back-end-1  |     mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
> pythonpoc-django-back-end-1  |           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> pythonpoc-django-back-end-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
> pythonpoc-django-back-end-1  |     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
> pythonpoc-django-back-end-1  |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> pythonpoc-django-back-end-1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1206, in _gcd_import
> pythonpoc-django-back-end-1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1178, in _find_and_load
> pythonpoc-django-back-end-1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1149, in _find_and_load_unlocked
> pythonpoc-django-back-end-1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked
> pythonpoc-django-back-end-1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 940, in exec_module
> pythonpoc-django-back-end-1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
> pythonpoc-django-back-end-1  |   File "/app/pythonPOC/settings.py", line 23, in <module>
> pythonpoc-django-back-end-1  |     con = oracledb.connect(user=env('DATABASE_USER'), password=env('DATABASE_PASSWORD'), dsn=env("DATABASE_DSN"),
> pythonpoc-django-back-end-1  |           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> pythonpoc-django-back-end-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/oracledb/connection.py", line 1012, in connect
> pythonpoc-django-back-end-1  |     return conn_class(dsn=dsn, pool=pool, params=params, **kwargs)
> pythonpoc-django-back-end-1  |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> pythonpoc-django-back-end-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/oracledb/connection.py", line 135, in __init__
> pythonpoc-django-back-end-1  |     impl.connect(params_impl)
> pythonpoc-django-back-end-1  |   File "src/oracledb/impl/thin/connection.pyx", line 298, in oracledb.thin_impl.ThinConnImpl.connect
> pythonpoc-django-back-end-1  |   File "src/oracledb/impl/thin/connection.pyx", line 189, in oracledb.thin_impl.ThinConnImpl._connect_with_params
> pythonpoc-django-back-end-1  |   File "src/oracledb/impl/thin/connection.pyx", line 162, in oracledb.thin_impl.ThinConnImpl._connect_with_description
> pythonpoc-django-back-end-1  |   File "src/oracledb/impl/thin/connection.pyx", line 111, in oracledb.thin_impl.ThinConnImpl._connect_with_address
> pythonpoc-django-back-end-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/oracledb/errors.py", line 111, in _raise_err
> pythonpoc-django-back-end-1  |     raise exc_type(_Error(message)) from cause
> pythonpoc-django-back-end-1  | oracledb.exceptions.OperationalError: DPY-6005: cannot connect to database. Connection failed with "[Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address"
> pythonpoc-django-back-end-1 exited with code 1
> pythonpoc-oracle-database-1  | SQL> ORACLE instance started.
> pythonpoc-oracle-database-1  | 
> pythonpoc-oracle-database-1  | Total System Global Area 1610611848 bytes
> pythonpoc-oracle-database-1  | Fixed Size                   9137288 bytes
> pythonpoc-oracle-database-1  | Variable Size              603979776 bytes
> pythonpoc-oracle-database-1  | Database Buffers   989855744 bytes
> pythonpoc-oracle-database-1  | Redo Buffers                 7639040 bytes
> pythonpoc-oracle-database-1  | 29465047
> pythonpoc-oracle-database-1  | ===========================================================
> pythonpoc-oracle-database-1  | 2022-10-28T14:15:14.712215+00:00
> pythonpoc-oracle-database-1  | Warning: VKTM detected a forward time drift.
> pythonpoc-oracle-database-1  | Time drifts can result in unexpected behavior such as time-outs.
> pythonpoc-oracle-database-1  | Please see the VKTM trace file for more details:
> pythonpoc-oracle-database-1  | /opt/oracle/diag/rdbms/orclcdb/ORCLCDB/trace/ORCLCDB_vktm_46.trc
> ```

My django-back-end container exited with the following error message :

> oracledb.exceptions.OperationalError: DPY-6005: cannot connect to database. Connection failed with "[Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address"

I have noticed in my Docker Desktop that my oracle-database container is still running. I have successfully tried to access my Oracle database from SQL Developer as SYS or with a new user that I created. I have executed `SELECT SYSDATE FROM dual` and It returns current date.

If I try to run my django-back-end with `python manage.py runserver`, everything works and I am able to access to my Oracle database which is running on the container launched with docker-compose previously. Note that I didn't change anything in my `.env` file.

```
(venv) PS D:\Vianney\Documents\Projets\pythonPOC> python manage.py runserver
Do we have a good connection : True
Are we using a Thin connection : True
Database version : 19.3.0.0.0
Do we have a good connection : True
Are we using a Thin connection : True
Database version : 19.3.0.0.0
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
October 28, 2022 - 17:12:40
Django version 4.1.2, using settings 'pythonPOC.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/    
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
```

`Dockerfile` (root level) :

```
FROM python:3

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

WORKDIR /app

COPY requirements.txt /app
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

CMD python manage.py runserver
```

`requirements.txt` :

```
asgiref==3.5.2
cffi==1.15.1
cryptography==38.0.1
distlib==0.3.6
Django==4.1.2
django-environ==0.9.0
filelock==3.8.0
oracledb==1.1.1
platformdirs==2.5.2
pycparser==2.21
sqlparse==0.4.3
tzdata==2022.5
virtualenv==20.16.6
```

`settings.py` :

```
import environ
import oracledb

sys.modules["cx_Oracle"] = oracledb

# Initialise environment variables
env = environ.Env()
environ.Env.read_env()

con = oracledb.connect(user=env('DATABASE_USER'), password=env('DATABASE_PASSWORD'), dsn=env("DATABASE_DSN"),
                       port=env('DATABASE_PORT'))

print('Do we have a good connection :', con.is_healthy())
print('Are we using a Thin connection :', con.thin)
print('Database version :', con.version)
```

My `.env` file which is at same level that `settings.py` :

```
SECRET_KEY=<my_secret_key>
DEBUG=True

DATABASE_ENGINE=django.db.backends.oracle
DATABASE_NAME=ORCLCDB
DATABASE_USER=c##vaccart
DATABASE_PASSWORD=<my_password>
DATABASE_HOST=localhost
DATABASE_PORT=1521
DATABASE_DSN=localhost/ORCLCDB
```

I am stuck since two days so any help will be appreciated. Ask me if you need more informations !

I have also tried to create an image of my django-back-end and run it with the hope it will connect to Oracle database. Got the same error message...

Comment: Check related questions like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70405638/how-can-i-connect-to-the-oracle-database-between-docker-containers

Comment: Indeed I was using `localhost` instead of `oracle_db` in my `.env` file. This related topic solved my problem. Thank you for your help @ChristopherJones !